# Java Equivalent code for python's Base64 conversion

Tags: java, python, encoding, base64, mp3

I am using python's `base64.b64encode()` function to encode a file(txt,mp3 etc)
I need java equivalent function for the same.Currently i am using the function `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(content.getBytes());` to encode the file in java.The **result is same** in the case of **txt** files(in both java and python) but **differs in the case of mp3** files.

Is there any encoding method in java to obtain the same result?If not, other encoding schemes to obtain the same result in both the languages?

Comment: Perhaps the encodings you are using in Java and Python are not the same.  In any case, this shouldn't matter assuming that the same process (Java or Python) is doing both the base 64 encoding and decoding.  Is this not the case?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!